# Illinois drivers license to French permis de conduire

Tags: driving-license

My son Joseph received his Illinois drivers license  18 months ago.
Since he has double nationality French/USA, he applied to exchange his Illinois permit for a French permis de conduire.

We received a temporary drivers license from Nantes but they have now said we have to prove that he has lived in the US for one year. I understand that proof of residence is not needed if he is bi-national.   Can you confirm this information?

Answer (score 1):

The webpage [Échange d'un permis de conduire passé à l'étranger (installation durable)](https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F1460) has a dedicated tab for French nationals.

It explicitly mentions that among the required documents, you must provide a proof of (former) residency in the country that has issued the foreign driving license.

> Copie de justificatif(s) de résidence dans le pays de délivrance de
> mon permis à la date de sa délivrance (185 jours au moins sur l'année
> civile d'obtention du permis, avec attaches personnelles et/ou
> professionnelles). Par exemple, attestation d'inscription et radiation
> des registres consulaires, contrat de travail et fiches de paye,
> attestation de scolarité et bulletins de notes, etc.

Therefore, it seems that your understanding that a proof of former foreign residence is not needed because your son is a French national is incorrect.